# How do I remove directory references from chm file generated by the Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I want to generate documentation in Windows Help format (chm) free of any directory references. In all my attempts, Doxygen always generated set of dir_*.html files containing information about ?source files? directories. This information is not visible in the chm document unless you start searching for keyword ?name of source file?; this search command seems to find reference to respective dir_*.html file and by clicking on it you see full directory path. Can you please advise how to suppress either generating those dir_*.html files completely or just displaying references to those files in the search result window of the chm documentation?

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve this?